# Are there commonly used equations for short-term overpower of wirewound resistors?

Tags: power, resistors, power-electronics, design

If I have a wirewound resistor rated for 250 W that might need to dissipate, say, 400 W for several seconds, is there a commonly used equation for finding its temperature rise or time to failure under overpower conditions?

I have found equations for wire temperature rise in inductors and transformers, but nothing for wirewounds.

Comment: You should just look up whitepapers on pulse power handling of wire-wound resistors (which are the best at these kinds of things.) See: [Pulse handling capabilities of wirewound resistors -- Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/49076/_wirewound_resistors_pulse_handling_capabilities_vmn_pl0396_1604.pdf), for example. There are many such papers around. Aircraft have special requirements, as well: [DO-160](https://aerospacepal.com/do-160-pulse-resistor-design-guide/)

Comment: Thanks. Half the battle is knowing the right term to search for.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: The resistor data sheet should contain the info you need. Please link it.